# Does the order of RewriteRule flags matter?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I could not find documentation that says the order of the flags in RewriteRule matter.  I don't think it does, but would like to get confirmation.

Are these two equivalent?

```
RewriteRule ^/test(.*) https://example.com/sites/test$1 [NC,R,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^/test(.*) https://example.com/sites/test$1 [NC,NE,R,L]
```

Comment: No, they do not matter.

Comment: Do you actually have a problem?

Comment: @arco444: I converted your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, the order of flags in a single RewriteRule does not matter.